# Exporting Vehicle Routing Problem Solution Tables in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I want to export the "Orders" and "Routes" tables/shapefiles that come as a result of solving a Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) in ModelBuilder.

However, I don't see where these layers are temporarily saved so that I can export them and store them in a specific location in my documents folder.

I have tried with "Copy Features" and "Feature Class to Feature Class" with no success (ArcGIS 10.2.2, advanced license).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this a while ago, so I want to share it in case someone finds it useful.

The [Select Data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/select-data.htm) tool did the trick. It allowed me to target the particular Child Data Element within the VRP layer that I wanted to export, and then, [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) exported the layer as a shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

These feature sets are stored in memory. You can find them in the results window, expanding the solve vehicle routing problem, expand inputs, right-click the feature set you want and Add to Display. You can also look at the List by Source button in the table of contents to see where the data is stored.